# Let a function $f(x)= \sqrt{(x^2-2x+2)(-x^2+3x+10)}-\sqrt{(-x^{2}+x-1)(x^{2}+x-6)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let a function $f(x)= \sqrt{(x^2-2x+2)(-x^2+3x+10)}-\sqrt{(-x^{2}+x-1)(x^{2}+x-6)}$ and its domain is $D=[a,b+c]$. What's the value of $a^3+b^3+c^3 \over abc$ ?

Any ideas ?

The answer is $\boxed{3}$ .

Comment: $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$

Answer (score 1):

in the first term $x^2-2x+2$ is always greater than $0$. hence $-x^2+3x+10$ should be greater than or equal to $0$.

similarly for the second term $-x^2+x-1$ is always less than $0$. hence $x^2+x-6$ should be less than or equal to $0$.

now find the common interval in which both inequality satisfies . the domain will be $[-2,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way :

Take the individual quadratic equations in the first sqrt and then put both of them greater than 0 and smaller than 0 simultaneously . You will get a particular domain for that . Similarly do it with the other sqrt term . Then take the common intersection of the two domains .

Seeing the question I think $a$ will come to be an integer and $b+c$ it will be of the form of a integer + irrational . Get the values and put it what you want to find !